# Get counts and document detail

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this one:

```
[{
    "_id": "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24cc",
    "voucher": "77-SRNP-4",
    "Collection Date": "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
    "Herbivore species": "Agrius cingulata",
    "Herbivore subfamily": "Sphinginae",
    "Latitude": "10.83764",
    "Longitude": "-85.61871"
}, {
    "_id": "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24ea",
    "voucher": "78-SRNP-10",
    "Collection Date": "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
    "Herbivore species": "Xylophanes turbata",
    "Herbivore subfamily": "Macroglossinae",
    "Latitude": "10.80212",
    "Longitude": "-85.65372"
}, {
    "_id": "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24eb",
    "voucher": "78-SRNP-10.02",
    "Collection Date": "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
    "Herbivore species": "Xylophanes turbata",
    "Herbivore subfamily": "Macroglossinae",
    "Latitude": "10.80212",
    "Longitude": "-85.65372"
}]
```

I would like to get the count of species and also some detail of each record on a single query. Something like the oposite of `$unwind`. To obtain something like:

```
[{
    "Agrius cingulata": {
        count: 1,
        "Herbivore subfamily": "Sphinginae"
        records: [{
            "voucher": "77-SRNP-4",
            "Collection Date": "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
            "Latitude": "10.83764",
            "Longitude": "-85.61871"
        }]

    },
    "Xylophanes turbata": {
        count: 2,
        "Herbivore subfamily": "Macroglossinae",
        records: [
            {
                "voucher": "78-SRNP-10",
                "Collection Date": "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                "Latitude": "10.80212",
                "Longitude": "-85.65372"
            },
            {
                "voucher": "78-SRNP-10.02",
                "Collection Date": "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                "Latitude": "10.80212",
                "Longitude": "-85.65372"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

I currently have this working on two separate queries, one to find the records and other for the counts. However the payload is a a bit big and I figure I could reduce it if I only send one time information that is repeated like species subfamily and also get the counts and other stats bundled up, but I haven't found the appropriate aggregation.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I currently have this working on two separate queries, ..."*  - A bit of advice. The next time you ask a question here, instead of saying *"... I have this code that works ..."* - then please just include the code you used. At the very least, it shows you have made some effort and it also gives an indication of what you expect as output. Even if you did not include an expected output within the question. It just makes a better question if you can demonstrate your own efforts in attempting to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Herbivore species",
            records: { $push: { Longitude: "$Longitude", Latitude: "$Latitude", "Collection Date": "$Collection Date", voucher: "$voucher" } },
            count : { $sum :1}
        }
    }
])
```

Results :

```
{
    "_id" : "Xylophanes turbata",
    "records" : [
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.65372",
            "Latitude" : "10.80212",
            "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10"
        },
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.65372",
            "Latitude" : "10.80212",
            "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10.02"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 2
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "Agrius cingulata",
    "records" : [
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.61871",
            "Latitude" : "10.83764",
            "Collection Date" : "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "77-SRNP-4"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 1
}
```

To Group "Herbivore species" and "Herbivore subfamily" both you can try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { "Herbivore species" :"$Herbivore species" , "Herbivore subfamily": "$Herbivore subfamily" },
            records: { $push: { Longitude: "$Longitude", Latitude: "$Latitude", "Collection Date": "$Collection Date", voucher: "$voucher" } },
            count : { $sum :1}
        }
    }
])
```

Result will be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "Herbivore species" : "Xylophanes turbata",
        "Herbivore subfamily" : "Macroglossinae"
    },
    "records" : [
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.65372",
            "Latitude" : "10.80212",
            "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10"
        },
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.65372",
            "Latitude" : "10.80212",
            "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10.02"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 2
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "Herbivore species" : "Agrius cingulata",
        "Herbivore subfamily" : "Sphinginae"
    },
    "records" : [
        {
            "Longitude" : "-85.61871",
            "Latitude" : "10.83764",
            "Collection Date" : "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
            "voucher" : "77-SRNP-4"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept to the *"reverse of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)"* is of course to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/). Therefore basically that's what you do, with some additional usage of [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) where that is appropriate as well as [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) along with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) since there should be no need to specify every field in the document, and especially where you actually have a lot more fields in the document than you present in the question.

The following is fairly generic and does not care how many other fields are present in the document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Herbivore species",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "Herbivore subfamily": { "$first": "$Herbivore subfamily" },
    "records": {
      "$push": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", ["Herbivore subfamily", "Herbivore species"] ] } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That would produce a result like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "Agrius cingulata",
        "count" : 1,
        "Herbivore subfamily" : "Sphinginae",
        "records" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24cc",
                        "voucher" : "77-SRNP-4",
                        "Collection Date" : "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
                        "Latitude" : "10.83764",
                        "Longitude" : "-85.61871"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "Xylophanes turbata",
        "count" : 2,
        "Herbivore subfamily" : "Macroglossinae",
        "records" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24ea",
                        "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10",
                        "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                        "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                        "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24eb",
                        "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10.02",
                        "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                        "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                        "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                }
        ]
}
```

Not *exactly* what was asked for in the question since it does not of course *exactly* show the "keys" of the result in the way asked for. But that can be amended with a second [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage along with the same operators show before:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Herbivore species",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "Herbivore subfamily": { "$first": "$Herbivore subfamily" },
    "records": {
      "$push": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", ["Herbivore subfamily", "Herbivore species"] ] } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "content": {
      "$mergeObjects": {
        "$arrayToObject": [[
          { "k": "$_id",
            "v": {
              "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                  "cond": { "$ne": ["$$this.k", "_id"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$content" } }
])
```

Which returns:

```
{
        "Xylophanes turbata" : {
                "count" : 2,
                "Herbivore subfamily" : "Macroglossinae",
                "records" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24ea",
                                "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10",
                                "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                        },
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24eb",
                                "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10.02",
                                "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "Agrius cingulata" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "Herbivore subfamily" : "Sphinginae",
                "records" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24cc",
                                "voucher" : "77-SRNP-4",
                                "Collection Date" : "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.83764",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.61871"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Or if you prefer ( since it does not change the amount of data returned anyway ) then you can simply "reduce" into the "key/value" form of returned document in client code, after the result is returned from MongoDB. A simple JavaScript "shell" example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Herbivore species",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "Herbivore subfamily": { "$first": "$Herbivore subfamily" },
    "records": {
      "$push": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "cond": { "$not": { "$in": [ "$$this.k", ["Herbivore subfamily", "Herbivore species"] ] } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  /*
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": [[
        { "k": "$_id",
          "v": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                "cond": { "$ne": ["$$this.k", "_id"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]]
    }
  }}
  */
]).toArray().reduce((o,{ _id, ...rest }) => ({ ...o, [_id]: rest }),{})
```

And the same result:

```
{
        "Xylophanes turbata" : {
                "count" : 2,
                "Herbivore subfamily" : "Macroglossinae",
                "records" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24ea",
                                "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10",
                                "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                        },
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24eb",
                                "voucher" : "78-SRNP-10.02",
                                "Collection Date" : "1978-05-20T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.80212",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.65372"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "Agrius cingulata" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "Herbivore subfamily" : "Sphinginae",
                "records" : [
                        {
                                "_id" : "5ba6b67ab22f62939eba24cc",
                                "voucher" : "77-SRNP-4",
                                "Collection Date" : "1977-06-06T06:00:00.000Z",
                                "Latitude" : "10.83764",
                                "Longitude" : "-85.61871"
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

---

Probably the main thing to grasp is "aggregating" ( which is what the **first** presented stage is doing ) is probably something you actually want the database server to be doing. You can use the *"fancy"* operators or *not*, depending on the MongoDB version you have available. However *"end result transformations"* as has been demonstrated as a *second phase* in the examples here is probably something you really want to do in the accepting client and processing code instead. It's usually much more straightforward and clean to do so this way.